# Hyper-V virtual machines goes to saved state when RDP disconnects, how do I prevent it?

Tags: hyper-v

I'm running Hyper-V on Windows 10 Pro, and the last couple of days Hyper-V have started to put my virtual machines to sleep / saved state when I disconnect from the host after controlling it via RDP. Then when I reconnect via Remote Desktop the virtual machines starts running again.

I'm guessing something has changed in a recent Windows update?
Are there any settings to prevent this new behavior?